# How to join weighted attribute from polygons to point

Tags: qgis

I would like to join attribute from polygons to green point. Are there some methods? Something like "weighted mean by distance" of attribute from polygons or else...

[image: Point and polygon]

Comment: Hi Andrew, and welcome to GIS.SE. Your question is currently unclear: what do you mean by weighted mean? Weighted by distance (from polygons to the green point), by polygon size, by something else? Please [edit] your question to add more details.